# Smart tires idea: How to measure electrical output of piezo arrays?

Tags: piezoelectricity

I had an idea where you take piezoelectric material and insert it into/on tires (or tire sleeve), suspension components, bushings etc of automobiles and then store the electric energy generated to help make the battery last longer.

Let’s say we put 40 rows of piezoelectric discs on each of the tires. In each row on the tire there are 10 piezoelectric discs for a total of 400 per tire. If each piezoelectric disc generates 1mW then altogether one row would generate 10mW per tire. Let’s also assume the rows are lined up and when the tire turns all the piezo discs generate electricity at same time on a row and synced with the other tires. So every time the vehicle moves 2cm the tire would fall on center of any row of piezos. For reference: The piezos would be 1cm diameter and each row spaced 1cm apart from next row.

So if starting on center of a row of piezos on all tires synced together, if every time the vehicle rolls 2cm the greatest amount of weight is on any given row’s center and would generate 40mW of electricity.

How to best quantify this energy? The more distance you go the more power generated. The faster you go the same distance the faster the power is generated. Output is directly related to time and frequency.

I did some math and figured every time the car moves a mile it would generate 3,218.688 watts if it stored the energy generated in capacitors and without any losses.

1 mile = 5280 feet
5280 feet = 160934.4 centimeters

Since every 2cm you generate 40mW from piezo array then divide mile by 2cm which equals 80,467.2 which would be the frequency of output per mile.

Output frequency of 80,467.2 * .040 watts equals 3,218.688 watts.

So if going 60mph you would reach that amount in one minute.

Is there a way to translate this into joules? Is that a better representation of this energy? Or is wattage better? Is my math correct?

Comment: Just use a better alternator.  The losses (and cost) of piezo elements in rubber aren't worth what you get out.  Not to mention the difficulties and loss involved in getting the energy from the rotating tire to car.

Comment: No offense and I appreciate you entertaining the idea however I did not ask for that. I provided an output of 40mW per 2cm and a distance. I want to know the best way to represent this energy and if my math is correct assuming the noted conditions in post.

Comment: @StevanWhite - No offense to you but part of engineering is to evaluate the feasibility of ideas and discount those that are not feasible. The comments provided by JRE are totally valid when a vehicle is powered by some energy source the best solution for generating a conversion of that energy to electrical energy will be to tap into energy source as close to the source as possible.

Comment: Watts are a measure of power, you'd be measuring the energy produced per flexing cycle in Joules. 3200 joules over a minute would average out to about 50W, which would be worthwhile, though small in comparison to the overall output of a vehicle.

Comment: Please show your work for the initial result that you generate 40mW by rolling 2cm. Why do you believe you will generate 1mW per disk? Note that the vehicle's weight is not "on any given row's center" it spread over the considerable area of the tire's footprint. Also, you **must** learn the difference between power and energy...40mW is not very interesting in an automotive application.

Comment: Can somebody migrate this to physics.stackexchange.com? I think this would suit better into there, because the mechanical parameters are more relevant than the electrical ones

Comment: You assume 10mW/tire synchronized to get 40mW in the car.  You are adding sensors, wires and electronics to tires plus some way to get synchronized power to car.  Somewhere the conservation of energy will catch up to you.

Answer (score 2):

A 1.25x1.5x0.02", 15nF, +10.23mm deflection, 1.77 N/m stiffness, PZT 5A, [Piezo Electric Harvester](https://piezo.com/collections/piezoelectric-energy-harvesters/products/piezoelectric-bending-transducer-t220-a4br-1305xb), two layer plate costs $33.00 each, per 100 units, and generates 17mW Power and 5mA at 8g 420Hz vibration, which could be enough to power most [RF electronics devices](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4168512/) at the tire.

A [standard tire](https://www.edmunds.com/car-maintenance/how-old-and-dangerous-are-your-tires.html) costs $150 and last 3 to 4 years.

For generating 1W per tire with 60 units, good for most power consuming electronics with 3.3V and 300mA available, for a very small LED light, and insuficcient for anything else, like car lights and other systems, and assuming all the mechanical parameters for the piezo device are met, and ignoring inefficiencies, the main reason for not using piezo tires is **the final cost**.

Raising the power rating to 1W will require $2000, and a whole set of 5 piezo tires would cost the same than an old used car.

Normally this should be a deal breaker the use of piezos for anything else than RF sensors, but a high end car focused on some key safety product as added value would use those piezos if they can be naturally integrated without problematic issues into the manufacturing process.

Answer (score 2):

> I did some math and figured every time the car moves a mile it would generate 3,218.688 watts if it stored the energy generated in capacitors and without any losses.

Something is wrong there. The watt (W) is a unit of power. Energy is measured in joules (J).

> So if starting on center of a row of piezos on all tires synced together, if every time the vehicle rolls 2 cm the greatest amount of weight is on any given row’s center and would generate 40 mW of electricity.

Let's assume you could extract a continuous power output of 40 mW from the tyres then the tyres will give increased rolling resistance. If you were able to get an efficiency of, say, 25% then the engine would need to supply an extra 160 mW to overcome this increased rolling resistance. With an engine efficiency of, say 30%, you would require 533 mW of fuel input.

Meanwhile the engine is running at 50 kW or so. Your battery top-up would be worth 0.001%. (i.e. It's a complete waste of time.)

For comparison, a decent solar panel on the roof of the car might give 20 to 50 W or so to keep your battery topped up without the complexity of getting power from the tires.